# JavaScript shutting off other JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there some feature in javascript that allows me to make other specific parts of the javascript code, inert?

Let's say, for example, that I have a few lines of jquery code that continuously manipulate the DOM (like a "marquee"), but there are specfic times when that code is completely useless, and those specific lines of code need to cease.

Is there a feature inherent to javascript that shuts off specific lines of code when certain conditions are true?

Comment: Yes — we call them "if statements".

Answer (score 1):

You can disable a function defined anywhere like this:

```
otherFunction = function() {}
```

Comment: If you need to 're-attach' the removed code, you could do something like `_copyFunc = otherFunction;` first, so that you can push the functionality back to `otherFunction` when you are done blocking it via `otherFunction = _copyFunc`, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
function doStuff() {
    // do my fancy jQuery stuff in this function.
}

if ( condition ) {
     doStuff();
}
```